# jquery handle mouseover mouseleave option

Tags: jquery

I have the following isse:

I have a select menu like this:

```
<select id="selectClass" name="bookClass" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true">
    <option selected="selected" value="A">CLASS A</option>
    <option value="B">CLASS B</option>
    <option value="C">CLASS C</option>
    <option value="D">CLASS D</option>
</select>
```

and I want to handle the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` event for each option element of the `<select>` (I don't want handle the mouseover, mouseleave event for the select). How can I do that?

Comment: what are you trying to do with mouseover/mouseout on the options?

Comment: You could create a list <ul> and make it visible/hidden just like a <select>, when the user clicks on some opening trigger. And then, you could capture the mouse events of each element of the list.

Comment: to hunter: for each option i want to show a tip with a description of the current option

Comment: to frenchie : can't change the select with a list

Answer (score 3):

An `<option>` isn't a visible element in its own right.  It's just data for a `<select>` element, which in most cases is rendered with a native O/S control.

AFAIK this can't be done, at least not in a cross-browser fashion.  It does appear to work in Firefox.

**EDIT** it does actually also work in Webkit browsers but only if the `<select>` element has a `size` attribute, such that more than one `<option>` is visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/usXP6/)

```
$("option").on("mouseover", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $("p").text( $(this).val() );
});
```

**UPDATE:** sadly works in **Firefox only**

Comment: doesn't work for me in Chrome or Safari, but does in Firefox.  Would appear to be non-standard behaviour.

Comment: I do wonder if it's actually a "bug" that Webkit browsers don't support this.  There's nothing in the HTML5 spec that says that an `<option>` element _can't_ do a mouseover.

Comment: ah, Webkit requires a `size` attribute on the `<select>` element.

Comment: @Alnitak yeah, and it needs a size different from 1 - http://jsfiddle.net/usXP6/3/